# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 error

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2, gradle-dependencies

I have installed android studio 2.2 preview 1 but its throwing two errors 
1st error is   `dependency cannot be applied to groovy`   And the 2nd When ever i am creating the other activity it throws an error
     `gradle sync failed: could not find property 'compile on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.defaultdependencyhandlerdecorated@6f1ae0a5.`

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.www.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'

// Android Support library
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'

// Picasso
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// Testing dependencies
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Comment: What's your build file?

Comment: I have added the build file